# how to pass data from a servlet to jsp form field?

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets

I've have two forms in two jsp files. Where in I, submit the first form and save it in a the database using servlet. And then, I've go to other form to fill up the details. As in the second form I have few fields the same as first form. As I, enter the `dataid` in the second form automatically the `first name and last name` to be field matching the `dataid`.

how can I do this in a servlet?

```
<form>
Data id:<input type="text" name="dataid"><br>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
<input type="submit value="submit"/>
</form> 

<form>
Some id:<inut type="text" name="someid"><br>
Age:<input type="text" name="age"> <br>
Data id:<inut type="text" name="dataid"><br>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
<input type="submit" type="transmit">
</form>
```

Comment: One concern when u enter the dataId in second form , u want to extract the data from DB corresponding to the dataId and match it with first name and last name ??

Comment: When i enter dataid in second form i should extract corresponding first name and last name in the second form's fields. In other worrdi need to auto populate first name and last name as soon as I enter dataid from the db

Comment: make ajax call frm the form to extract the data corresponding to dataID of second form

Comment: I am not knowing how to do it sir? can u show a demo code?

Comment: sry dear.I dnt have such demo.You need to find it on google how to make ajaz call so simple to find

Comment: ok sir. I tried finding but dint find any apt ones

Comment: is it mandatory that u will go to the 2nd form as soon as you r done with the first form???@user3201640

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the parameters in the request you can simply write them in the `value`of the ìnput` tag. Something like:

```
<form>
Data id:<input type="text" name="dataid" value="<%=request.getParameter("dataid")%>"><br>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<%=request.getParameter("firstname")%>"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<%=request.getParameter("lastname")%>">
<input type="submit value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Take a look at [The Java EE 5 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaov.html)

Comment: I don't underestand, you mean 2 different pages? If you don't have the data in the request (because you did a redirect or something) you could store the data in the `session` and render it with `<%=session.getAttribute("firstname")%>`